# How can I save only a substring of file names from a directory without the file extension?

Tags: bash

I have a directory that I'm reading from and I want to save only the date representation as a string.
I am close to getting it , although I know there is probably an easier way. Here is what I have so far:

```
#files are in the format of "THIS_20200420.csv" so I want only "20200420"
```

```
declare -a arr
declare -a arr2
FILES=test2/*.csv

for file in $FILES
do
    arr=(${arr[*]} "${file##*/}")
done

for i in "${arr[@]}"
do
   arr2+=$(echo $i | cut -c6-13)
done

for item in "${arr2[@]}"
do
    echo $item
done
```

the output shows the array only having one element which is all the strings concatenated:

```
20200110202001202020021920200220202004202020042220200110202001202020021920200220202004202020042220200219202002202020042020200422
```

Im bashing my head against my computer at this point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
arr=(
"THIS_20200420.csv"
"THIS_20200421.csv"
"THIS_20200422.csv"
"THIS_20200423.csv"
"THIS_20200424.csv"
"THIS_20200425.csv"
"THIS_20200426.csv"
"THIS_20200427.csv"
"THIS_20200428.csv"
"THIS_20200429.csv"
"THIS_20200430.csv" )
arr=( ${arr[@]//*_} )
arr=( ${arr[@]//.*} )
echo "arr: ${arr[@]}"
```

**Explanation:**

`arr=( ${arr[@]//*_} )` will match all char up to '_' for each element, and replace them with empty string.

`arr=( ${arr[@]//.*} )` will match all char after '.' for each element, and replace them with empty string.

For more information on parameter expansion, a good reference is [TLDP's guide on parameter expansion](https://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/parameter-substitution.html).

Answer (score 0):

Use an array for the files assignment and parameter expansion.

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

shopt -s nullglob

##: Save the files ending in *.csv in an array 
## so it expands properly, variable assignment does not expand the glob *
files=(test2/*.csv)

##: Remain only the files that end with .csv without the pathname, longest match
files=("${files[@]##*/}")

##: Remain only the file names without the .csv extention
files=("${files[@]%.csv}")

##: Remain only the filename after the _ from the beginning, shortest match.
files=("${files[@]#*_}")

printf '%s ' "${files[@]}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Meet [Cut](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/cut-command-linux-examples/)! A good friend of Linux Users

```
for file in ./*.csv; do echo $file | cut -d "_" -f 2 | cut -d "." -f 1 ; done
```

This one line should do the trick!

Example:

[image: output]

Comment: [**Please do not upload images of text (code/input/output/errors, or otherwise) on Stack Overflow**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question). Please [edit] your answer, pasting all text into the answer with [correct formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
declare -a arrayname=($(ls -1 test2/*.csv |  grep -o '[0-9]*'))
```

Demo:

```
$ls -1 *csv
THIS_20200420.csv
THIS_20200421.csv
THIS_20200422.csv
THIS_20200423.csv
THIS_20200424.csv
THIS_20200425.csv
THIS_20200426.csv
THIS_20200427.csv
THIS_20200428.csv
THIS_20200429.csv
THIS_20200430.csv
$declare -a arrayname=($(ls -1 *csv |  grep -o '[0-9]*'))
$echo ${arrayname[@]}
20200420 20200421 20200422 20200423 20200424 20200425 20200426 20200427 20200428 20200429 20200430
$echo ${arrayname[2]}
20200422
$
```

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve this using a loop with awk:

```
$ for file in *.csv; do echo $file | awk -F '[^[:alnum:]]' '{print $2}'; done
```

The `-F '[^[:alnum:]]'` tells awk to use non alphanumeric characters as the delimiter.

Another way to do this is to use bash shell parameter expansion to echo only the part of the filename you want. This obviously only works if your filenames have consistent formatting:

```
$ for file in *.csv; do echo "${file:5:8}"; done
```

I thought it would be nice to use bash parameter expansion to strip the unwanted prefix and suffix but you can't have nested expansion (afaict) so this is the best I could come up with:

```
$ for file in *.csv; do echo "$(tmp=${file%.csv}; echo ${tmp#THIS_})"; done
```