# How do I avoid setting the value of an array when there is no files in the directory it's looking for?

Tags: bash

I can successfully save all the file names in an array from the given directory although I want to avoid setting a value for the array if there are no files present in that dir.

```
save_all_file_dates(){
       shopt -s xpg_echo
        filedates=(test2/*.csv)
        filedates=( ${filedates[@]//*_} )
        filedates=( ${filedates[@]//.*} )
        printf "\n"
}
```

I thought

```
shopt -s xpg_echo
```

would take care of if but it seems that when i remove all files from the dir, the value of the array still gets set to:

```
test2/*
```

Comment: I have that answered here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61604326/how-can-i-save-only-a-substring-of-file-names-from-a-directory-without-the-file but you seem to accept the other answer...

Comment: Also that parameter expansion you have is wrong, if you want to slice the beginning and the trailing part. do you know what `//` it means in parameter expansion?

Comment: The option you want is `nullglob`: `shopt -s nullglob`